# Print dictionary key/value from user input

Tags: python, c++

How can I efficiently accept user input from keyboard to print a dictionary key/value pair? My concern is the Python side of my code.

Currently working on a project for school, and I'm trying to print the item name, and the number of times it was "bought that day"

Project is in two languages, C++ and Python. First C++ code block and then Python

```
//Show menu
    while (true) {
        cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;
        cout << "*    1 - Display all items and # times purchased      *" << endl;
        cout << "*    2 - Display specific item and # times purchased  *" << endl;
        cout << "*    3 - Display graph of all items purchased         *" << endl;
        cout << "*    4 - Exit Program                                 *" << endl;
        cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;

        int userInput;  //obtain user input
        string userString; //obtain user input 
        cout << "Please enter a selection. 4 will exit program. ";
        cin >> userInput;
        switch (userInput) {
        case 1:
            CallProcedure("wholeList");
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Enter the name of the item you'd like to see history of: " << endl;
                cin >> userString;
            callIntFunc("specificItem", userString);
        
            break;
        case 3:
            //requirement 3
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Goodbye.";
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid input. Please try again";
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
def specificItem(userInput):
     with open('groceryList.txt', 'r') as f:
      groceryList = [line.strip() for line in f]
      Counter(groceryList)
      userInput = input()
      print(Counter(groceryList[userInput]))
```

My thought process is that if I enter this certain text file into the dictionary Counter, I should be able to then access which key/value pair via userInput. Am I overthinking this? This has been a huge learning curve to me, integrating the two languages and I'm looking for some insight for a novice.

Below is text file I'm using

```
Radishes
Broccoli
Peas
Cranberries
Broccoli
Potatoes
Cucumbers
Radishes
Cranberries
Peaches
Zucchini
Potatoes
Cranberries
Cantaloupe
Beets
Cauliflower
Cranberries
Peas
Zucchini
Peas
Onions
Potatoes
Cauliflower
Spinach
Radishes
Onions
Zucchini
Cranberries
Peaches
Yams
Zucchini
Apples
Cucumbers
Broccoli
Cranberries
Beets
Peas
Cauliflower
Potatoes
Cauliflower
Celery
Cranberries
Limes
Cranberries
Broccoli
Spinach
Broccoli
Garlic
Cauliflower
Pumpkins
Celery
Peas
Potatoes
Yams
Zucchini
Cranberries
Cantaloupe
Zucchini
Pumpkins
Cauliflower
Yams
Pears
Peaches
Apples
Zucchini
Cranberries
Zucchini
Garlic
Broccoli
Garlic
Onions
Spinach
Cucumbers
Cucumbers
Garlic
Spinach
Peaches
Cucumbers
Broccoli
Zucchini
Peas
Celery
Cucumbers
Celery
Yams
Garlic
Cucumbers
Peas
Beets
Yams
Peas
Apples
Peaches
Garlic
Celery
Garlic
Cucumbers
Garlic
Apples
Celery
Zucchini
Cucumbers
Onions
```

Comment: On the side note, why is your Python code ignoring the `userInput` that your C++ program has already read in and passed to `specificItem()`? By calling `input()` in your Python code, you are asking the user to re-enter their input again a 2nd time.

Comment: That was me trying to figure out how to get it to work. When I run the program, I have to enter it twice and I figured that was the reason.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how files work. `f` is the actual file object. Instead of this, you want to use the `f.read()` function, to read the whole file. Better than this, though, would be to do `f.readlines()` instead of your list comprehension:

```py
def specificItem(userInput):
     with open('groceryList.txt', 'r') as f:
          groceryList = f.readlines()
          Counter(groceryList)
          userInput = input()
          print(Counter(groceryList[userInput]))
```

Another thing - what is the use of `Counter(groceryList)`? What even is `Counter` doing? You might want to consider removing that.

Comment: The use of `Counter` is to count the amount of times a certain item appears within the groceryList.txt. I figured if I used `Counter` then it would be more easily accessible to print both the key and value.

Comment: @megargayu see the [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) documentation.

Comment: @MattTrembley you are using `Counter()` wrong.  It takes in an iterable list and creates a dictionary. But you are ignoring that dictionary. Try this instead: `groceryList = Counter(f.readlines()) print(groceryList[userInput])`

Comment: @RemyLebeau that did work, although it just printed 0 but it is better than the error I was receiving.

Comment: @MattTrembley did you verify the dictionary is being created correctly? What is the actual value of `userInput` when accessing `groceryList[userInput]`? Maybe it is not what you are expecting.

Comment: I added `print(groceryList, groceryList[userInput])` to see it in output. It is there, but at the end of the line I see 0.  

`Cranberries
Counter({'Cranberries\n': 10, 'Zucchini\n': 10, 'Cucumbers\n': 9, 'Peas\n': 8, 'Garlic\n': 8, 'Broccoli\n': 7, 'Cauliflower\n': 6, 'Celery\n': 6, 'Spinach\n': 5, 'Potatoes\n': 5, 'Peaches\n': 5, 'Yams\n': 5, 'Apples\n': 4, 'Radishes\n': 3, 'Beets\n': 3, 'Onions\n': 3, 'Cantaloupe\n': 2, 'Pumpkins\n': 2, 'Limes\n': 1, 'Pears\n': 1, 'Onions': 1}) 0'`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, I see, thanks. I thought it might have been user-defined, not `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @MattTrembley You didn't show what value `userInput` has.  But look at your dictionary, all of the keys end with `\n`, which you don't want. Chances are, `userInput` does not end with `\n` (`cin >> userString` in C++ certainly would not do that, I'm sure `input()` in Python is the same), thus would not match with any key, which is why `groceryList[userInput]` returns 0. You tried to account for that in your original code using `line.strip()`, but that is lost in the new code. Try `groceryList = Counter([line.strip() for line in f])` instead of `groceryList = Counter(f.readlines())`